# How to add onclick listener on CardPane items (Gluon with JavaFX)

Tags: javafx, action, fxml, gluon

I use a CardPane component inside a fxml File :

```
<?import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.control.CardPane?>

<CardPane fx:id="cardList">
 <Label text="label1" />
 <Label text="label2" />
</CardPane>
```

With my controller :

```
public class Sample extends Pane {

@FXML
private CardPane cardList;

private final String FXML_FILE = "sample.fxml";

public Sample()
{
    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(FXML_FILE));
    fxmlLoader.setRoot(this);
    fxmlLoader.setController(this);

    try
    {
        fxmlLoader.load();
    }
    catch (IOException ioexception)
    {
        throw new RuntimeException(ioexception);
    }
}

protected void clickItem()
{
    System.out.println("The item 'x' was clicked!");
}
```

Is it possible to add a listener to the items of the CardPane so that when I click on one item i call clickItem() method ? How to proceed ? And how can I identify which item was clicked ?

Answer (score 0):

Here the solution I came with, please share your opinion on this approach :

```
 public XMLFileChooserComponentController()
{
   [...]

    ObservableList<Label> labels = xmlFiles.getItems();

    labels.forEach((label) -> {
        label.setOnMouseClicked(this::clickItem);
    });

}

public void clickItem(MouseEvent event)
{
    Label label = (Label) event.getSource();
    if (label.getId().equals("label1"))
    {
        System.out.println("The label " + label.getId() + " was clicked!");
    }
    if (label.getId().equals("label2"))
    {
        System.out.println("The label " + label.getId() + " was clicked!");
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a valid solution, of course. But if you are using FXML and you have just a fixed number of labels, why don't you add the event handler to each of those labels directly (SceneBuilder, Code tab-> `On Mouse Clicked`)?

Comment: yes this could work if i have a fixed number of labels, but in this case i don't that's why i am asking :-)

Comment: Of course it is. Note that `CardPane` is just a container, so you have to add its children at some point. When you do that you can already provide them with the required listeners.

Comment: yes that the solution I guess, as CardPane don't really need to know what's going on with it's children